# Merging two xml files LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, merge

I have problem merging two XML files. 
I loaded both files into two  objects, located the target nodes in both objects and tried to merge.

Here is a sample:

```
var nodes1 = XResult1.Descendants("subject");
var nodes2 = XResult2.Descendants("subject");

//nodes1.Add(nodes2.Nodes());
```

//*** Code to merge**** 
Can somebody pls help me.
Thanks in advance... BB

Here is my XResult1:

```
<subjects>
    <subject>
        <node id="1">
            Hi
        </node>
        <node id="2">
            Hi again
        </node>
        <node id="3">
            Hi once more
        </node>
    </subject>
</subjects>
```

Here is my XResult2 :

```
<subjects>
    <subject>
        <node id="4">
            Hello
        </node>
        <node id="5">
            Hello again
        </node>
    </subject>
</subjects>
```

And my final Result should be :

```
<subjects>
    <subject>
        <node id="1">
            Hi
        </node>
        <node id="2">
            Hi again
        </node>
        <node id="3">
            Hi once more
        </node>
        <node id="4">
            Hello
        </node>
        <node id="5">
            Hello again
        </node>

    </subject>
</subjects>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change:

```
XResult1.Descendants("subjects").FirstOrDefault(); 
XResult2.Descendants("subjects").FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
XResult1.Descendants("subject").FirstOrDefault();
XResult2.Descendants("subject").FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is a more complete example:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XResult1.xml");
XElement subjectElement = document.Descendants("subject").FirstOrDefault();

XDocument document2 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XResult2.xml");
XElement subjectElement2 = document2.Descendants("subject").FirstOrDefault();

subjectElement.Add(subjectElement2.Nodes());
```

Comment: @Russell. Thank you.  My system hangs at subjectElement.Add(subjectElement2.Nodes());

Comment: The other thing I noted is .FirstOrDefault() returns only the first <subject> but actually i need all the <subject>.

Comment: If you are saying you have more than one <subject> tag per XML document, then you need to update your question with the proper XML.

Comment: Okay.  So the problem with your code now is that you are not calling FirstOrDefault() as I show in my answer.  My answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the elements inside the `subject` element, you need to go down further in the tree, so set your `nodes1` and `nodes2` to the following:

```
XElement nodes2 = XResult2.Descendants("subjects").Descendants("subject").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Russell McClure you're right, for some reason I was thinking about lists. fixed.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() yeilds only the first <subject> element but actually I need all the <subject> elments in XResult2.

Comment: @BumbleBee your XML files show that you have only one `<subject>` element, which in turn has many `<node>` elements