# How to make an xml file with data from xsd?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

I was given a xsd file to use it and make a xml file with data.

This is what i planned to do, using an c# project in Visual Studio 2008

- Make a dataset from that xsd file:

  - added the mpc.xsd file to the project to create an DataSet
  - set MSDataSetGenerator to its property "PersonalizedTools"
  - open it with DataSet designer.
- Fill its datatables with data
- Use dataset.WriteXML to save data as XML.

The problem is when i want to instance it,

```
ds_mpc = new DATASETS.DS_MPC();
```

Gives the next error:

> "The same table 'X' cannot be the child table in two nested relations."

Is there an walk around to avoid that error? or Is there another way to use that xsd schema, populate within data and make a xml file.?

This is the link to that xsd file:  https://sppld.sat.gob.mx/pld/documentos/links/xsd/mpc.xsd

Comment: Potential repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd

Comment: You will need to post more steps... I've tried your XSD and I get a perfectly valid data set. The error you're getting is typically caused by certain types of XSDs, which doesn't seem to apply in your case.

Comment: Petru... how did u make an instance of it?  i couldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not an exact answer to your question, consider using an [online generator](http://www.xsd2xml.com/) or Altova XmlSpy.

Comment: Thanks, and how can i populate that XML and save it with xsd schema?

Comment: The real problem is when i instanciate it gives the error "The same table 'X' cannot be the child table in two nested relations."

Answer (score 0):

This is fixable, by cheating...

[Serialization Issue when using WriteXML method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125137/serialization-issue-when-using-writexml-method/29515870#29515870)

May not be perfect, but it worked for my scenario.